# How to get information from a static class that is called by an event handler?

Tags: c#, class, serial-port, abstraction

I am new to C# and to object-orientation in general having come from C.

My problem is that I trying to create a program that will read from multiple serialports at the same time. I have been given a program that processes a single serial port.

Currently I have a static function which is used to configure the 8 serial ports I wish to use. Within this static function I call:

SerialPortToSetup.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(SerialPortEventHandler);

This function itself calls a class to read data from the serialport and passes it back. How can I get at the information coming out of the SerialPort whilst attempting to maintain abstraction for the possibility of adding more SerialPorts later?

In the codes present state I get an error as flowmeter_data_array is not a static object and so cannot be called, and the function cannot be made non-static as the function which sets the event handler is static.

```
 private static void SetupSerialPort(SerialPort SerialPortToSetup, ComboBox PortNameComboBox, ComboBox BaudRateComboBox)
    {
        SerialPortToSetup.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(BaudRateComboBox.Text);
        SerialPortToSetup.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(SerialPortEventHandler);
        SerialPortToSetup.PortName = PortNameComboBox.Text;
    }

    private static void SerialPortEventHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        data_array[data_array.Length] = SerialData.GetSerialData((SerialPort) sender);
    }
```

The class so far is shown below

```
public static class SerialData
{
    public static string GetSerialData(SerialPort SerialPortSent)
    {
        string data_string = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            if (SerialPortSent.IsOpen)
            {
                data_string = SerialPortSent.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Serial Port not open", "Read Error",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                data_string = "ABORT CODE";
            }
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Read Buffer = NULL", "Read Error",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Recieve DUT data exception, Serial Port not open", "Read Error",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            data_string = "ABORT CODE";
        }

        return data_string;
    }
```

Previously the program used a single class for all of its calculations and operations. But I am also concerned that by creating a new class, then I will run into "Class Envy" by calling the class too much from my main class.

Thank you in advance for any help you may be able to offer me.

Comment: My question should really be, how can I re-arrange the structure of the program to suit my needs?

Or, should I call the datahandler explicitly outside the SetupSerialPort function? It would work but I feel that it would be a messy implementation.

Comment: Perhaps you should rethink your approach. Why do you need `static` classes and methods? Which of them could be changed to instance methods? Which objects could you instantiate? Your simple task is a good starting point for diving deeper into the OOP world.

Comment: @GMoney Although 'SetupSerialPort' is a static class, the parameter 'SerialPortToSetup' is an instance of a serial port. So each time the 'SetupSerialPort' is called, a 'SerialDataReceivedEventHandler' is attached to that instance of the serial port passed in; and that is ok as long as you destroy all serial port instances. But where you may want to be careful of is the 'data_array[data_array.Length]'. It is not clear from the code what is context of the 'data_array'; if this is in global scope then it may be misused or over used as you receive data from all serial ports.

Comment: @GMoney typo 'SetupSerialPort' is a static method.